# difference between blocks and controllers

Tags: php, magento

I have just started working with Magento, my programming experience is fairly limited and as a result I seem to be getting confused on what I am guessing should be fairly simple concepts.

What is the difference between a block and a controller?

I am reading 'Magento PHP developers guide' and it describes a block as:

> data resources that communicate directly with models, which manipulate the data, if needed and pass it onto the views

I dont understand why the blocks are needed, that paragraph says to me that they are just another controller, and why have two controllers to do one job?

Isn't it the job of the controller to communicate with the model and set data to the view?

Also when would you put information into a controller and when would you put information into a block?

Comment: Please refer :http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates

Answer (score 1):

There aren't much common between these two. The main purpose of controllers in magento is for handling request initializing everything and then output result of request to user. Each page is rendered with particular controller.

The blocks are 'building bricks', that you are able to dynamically manipulate through layout object, so each page is basically consists of blocks. The blocks bring magento that flexibility, so you are able to separate things one from another and use on their own. For example, you could create some information block, and then render it on different pages differently, passing parameters to it, moving it relatively to other blocks on the page.